# Asp.Net Core : Calculate two Persian dates and get the age?

Tags: asp.net-core

I have two Persian dates and I want the first date to be subtracted from the second date and to store the number as an age in a variable.

First Date :
`1399/01/01`
Second Date :
`1400/01/01`
I want the date to be calculated as follows?

Calcute : `1399` - `1400` = 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answers to my questions

```
  PersianCalendar pc = new PersianCalendar();
            var Birthdate =  pc.GetYear(DateTime.Parse(viewmodel.BirthDateDay));
            var DateNow = pc.GetYear(DateTime.Now);                
            var resault = ((Convert.ToInt32(DateNow) - Convert.ToInt32(Birthdate)) + " " + "سال");
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use PersianCalendar in .NET like code below then minus date2 from date1 which gives you a TimeSpan object (time between two dates).

```
        PersianCalendar pc = new PersianCalendar();
        DateTime dt1 = new DateTime(1399, 01, 01, pc);
        DateTime dt2 = new DateTime(1400, 01, 01, pc);
        TimeSpan timeBetween = dt2 - dt1;
        Console.WriteLine(timeBetween);
```

Comment: I have the date as follows
1399/01/01